# UIScrollView Zooming & contentInset

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, zooming, uiedgeinsets

Simliar to iOS Photos App where the user is zooming in and out of an image by pinching:

UIView > UIScrollView > UIImageView > UIImage

Initially, I had the issue of zooming below scale 1: image being off centered.  I got it fixed by doing this:

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offsetX = max((scrollView.bounds.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0)
        let offsetY = max((scrollView.bounds.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0)
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offsetY, offsetX, 0, 0)
}
```

This works well when zooming out.

UIImage content mode is aspectFit

### Issue

When I **ZOOM IN**, when zoomScale is above 1, scroll view insets need to hug the surroundings of the UIImage that the scroll view contains.  This takes away the dead-space that was surrounding the UIImage. IE, Photos app when zooming-in by pinching or double tapping.

### Tried

```
    func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.zoomScale > 1 {
        let imageScale = (self.imageView.bounds.width/self.imageView.image!.size.width)
        let imageWidth = self.imageView.image!.size.width * imageScale
        let imageHeight = self.imageView.image!.size.height * imageScale
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(((scrollView.frame.height - imageHeight) * 0.5), (scrollView.frame.width - imageWidth) * 0.5 , 0, 0)
        print (scrollView.contentInset.top)
    }
    else {

        let offsetX = max((scrollView.bounds.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0)
        let offsetY = max((scrollView.bounds.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0)
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offsetY, offsetX, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

Above addition seems to vary the inset amount still.

### Update (images added)

First image shows the default layout.  Rest shows when zoomed in.....

[image]

Comment: So, you want to stop before the dead-space will appear?

Comment: Updated the question with graphical illustrations.

Comment: Only difference in 2nd & 3rd picture is scrollview is only scaled on x-axis in 3rd one. But what difference does it make to image ? Scaling of image is same in 2nd & 3rd pictures. Do you just want it exactly like photos app ?

Comment: @Gurdeep : 3rd image has trimmed Scroll View Insets.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your approach looks correct. You need to update your code as below.

```
    func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    if scrollView.zoomScale > 1 {
        
        if let image = imageView.image {
            
            let ratioW = imageView.frame.width / image.size.width
            let ratioH = imageView.frame.height / image.size.height
            
            let ratio = ratioW < ratioH ? ratioW:ratioH
            
            let newWidth = image.size.width*ratio
            let newHeight = image.size.height*ratio
            
            let left = 0.5 * (newWidth * scrollView.zoomScale > imageView.frame.width ? (newWidth - imageView.frame.width) : (scrollView.frame.width - scrollView.contentSize.width))
            let top = 0.5 * (newHeight * scrollView.zoomScale > imageView.frame.height ? (newHeight - imageView.frame.height) : (scrollView.frame.height - scrollView.contentSize.height))
            
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, top, left)
        }
    } else {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
}
```

Swift 5

```
    func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    if scrollView.zoomScale > 1 {

        if let image = imageView.image {

            let ratioW = imageView.frame.width / image.size.width
            let ratioH = imageView.frame.height / image.size.height

            let ratio = ratioW < ratioH ? ratioW:ratioH

            let newWidth = image.size.width*ratio
            let newHeight = image.size.height*ratio

            let left = 0.5 * (newWidth * scrollView.zoomScale > imageView.frame.width ? (newWidth - imageView.frame.width) : (scrollView.frame.width - scrollView.contentSize.width))
            let top = 0.5 * (newHeight * scrollView.zoomScale > imageView.frame.height ? (newHeight - imageView.frame.height) : (scrollView.frame.height - scrollView.contentSize.height))

            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: left, bottom: top, right: left)
        }
    } else {
        scrollView.contentInset = .zero
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.zoomScale > 1 {
        if let image = imageView.image {

            let ratioW = imageView.frame.width / image.size.width
            let ratioH = imageView.frame.height / image.size.height

            let ratio = ratioW < ratioH ? ratioW : ratioH

            let newWidth = image.size.width * ratio
            let newHeight = image.size.height * ratio

            let left = 0.5 * (newWidth * scrollView.zoomScale > imageView.frame.width ? (newWidth - imageView.frame.width) : (scrollView.frame.width - scrollView.contentSize.width))
            let top = 0.5 * (newHeight * scrollView.zoomScale > imageView.frame.height ? (newHeight - imageView.frame.height) : (scrollView.frame.height - scrollView.contentSize.height))

            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: left, bottom: top, right: left)
        }
    } else {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for swift 4

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView.zoomScale > 1 {

            if let image = self.imageViewZoom.image {

                let ratioW = self.imageViewZoom.frame.width / image.size.width
                let ratioH = self.imageViewZoom.frame.height / image.size.height

                let ratio = ratioW < ratioH ? ratioW:ratioH

                let newWidth = image.size.width*ratio
                let newHeight = image.size.height*ratio

                let left = 0.5 * (newWidth * scrollView.zoomScale > self.imageViewZoom.frame.width ? (newWidth - self.imageViewZoom.frame.width) : (scrollView.frame.width - scrollView.contentSize.width))
                let top = 0.5 * (newHeight * scrollView.zoomScale > self.imageViewZoom.frame.height ? (newHeight - self.imageViewZoom.frame.height) : (scrollView.frame.height - scrollView.contentSize.height))

                scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, top, left)
            }
        } else {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        }
    }
```