# How to deal with offsets in UIScrollView zooming for UIImageview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Simply I have `UIScrollView` with one view for zooming inside that view: `UIImageView`.

This is how it looks when I just display the image:

[image]

When I pinch:

[image]

And when I swipe down after pinch:

[image]

And now I have black space I do not want to see. Is there a way to set some offsets and prevent from scrolling far after the image?

In code I simply use:

```
//MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

public func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return photoImageView
}
```

Comment: Is the black area part of the image?

Comment: No, `UIScrollView` fits the screen. Within `UIScrollView` there is an `UIImageView` with `.ScaleAspectFit` contentMode. The `backgroundColor` of controller is black. `UIImageView` has exactly the same size what `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Do you have any idea what to work with? I suppose it is about content offsets, insets...

Comment: Sorry I was researching this problem, looking for some inspiration, but I think I am out of my area of expertise.

Comment: Hello @BartłomiejSemańczyk, did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue, please advice.

Comment: @AhmadF please see my answer below

Comment: Founded answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460256/uiscrollview-zooming-contentinset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
//MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

public func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return photoImageView
}

public func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let imageViewSize = photoImageView.frame.size
    let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size

    let verticalPadding = imageViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height ? (scrollViewSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2 : 0
    let horizontalPadding = imageViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width ? (scrollViewSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2 : 0

    if verticalPadding >= 0 {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalPadding, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: verticalPadding, right: horizontalPadding)
    } else {
        scrollView.contentSize = imageViewSize
    }
}
```

and prepare view on `viewDidLoad`:

```
private func setupInitialView() {

    photoImageView.sizeToFit()

    let imageViewSize = photoImageView.bounds.size
    let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    let widthScale = scrollViewSize.width / imageViewSize.width
    let heightScale = scrollViewSize.height / imageViewSize.height

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
    scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.minimumZoomScale, animated: false)

    scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView)
}
```

Comment: Cheers Up! thank you for sharing your solution, it works fine for me, so I suggest to accept it.

Comment: Hello! I know this is an old question, but for me code is not working. Any chance you can show your constraints? cz let imageViewSize = photoImageView.bounds.size will write here not an image size but imageView size == fullscreen (from your comments). I have the same case as you, but for me this solution isn't working. Thanks